# Enviar id dinamicos en POST a otro archivo php

Tags: php, javascript

Hola estoy creando unos inputs dinamicos de la siguiente forma:

```
$(".reporteBody").append('<input type="text" name="titulo' + y + '" id="tiulo' + y + '" value="Caja # ' + y + '">');
```

Digamos que se crean 3 inputs, y como estan dentro de un form, mediante un boton los estoy pasando a otro archivo php mediante `POST` y lo recibo asi:

```
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    $titulo.$i.=$_POST['titulo'.$i];
}
```

Pero me da error cuando visualizo el archivo no en el editor, cual es la forma correcta de pasar estos valores dinamicos (sin importar el número) y mostrarlos correctamente?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en el:

```
$titulo.$i.=$_POST['titulo'.$i];
```

Ahí no sé exactamente que es lo que quieres escribir. Si fuera un array sería:

```
$titulo[$i] = $_POST['titulo'.$i];
```

Que sería lo más recomendable.

Entre otras cosas enviar la infromación desde el formulario como arreglo es incluso mucho más estable y controlable. te lo recomiendo.